# How to select Xpath element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am playing around with connect automation in Linkedin and trying to send custom connection message to search list.

The way I do it, first I find all buttons. Then I find XPath of the names and index it.
Then I fill all_names list. Then this names are inserted into greeting message.

The problem I face is that search result list does not only contain Connect buttons but also sometimes Follow button and that messes up the index, which results in wrong name being added to the greeting message.

Here is the code part:

```
driver.get(
    "https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?network=%5B%22S%22%5D&origin=FACETED_SEARCH&page=7")
time.sleep(2)
# ----------------------------------------------------------------

all_connect_buttons = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'button')
connect_buttons = [
    btn for btn in all_connect_buttons if btn.text == "Connect"]

all_names = []
all_span = driver.find_elements(
    By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@class,'app-aware-link ')]/span[@dir='ltr']/span[@aria-hidden='true']")

idx = [*range(1, 11)]
for j in range(len(idx)):
    #get only first name
    name = all_span[j].text.split(" ")[0]
    all_names.append(name)

    # print(name)
```

So basically I have types of buttons:

```
<span class="artdeco-button__text">
     Connect
</span>
```

and

```
<span class="artdeco-button__text">
     Follow
</span>
```

Is it somehow possible to filter only Connect button names so that Follow names are not added to all_span list? Can it be done with some XPath of Python expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of collecting all `button` elements you can make more precise locating.
This Xpath will give you "Connect" buttons only `//button[contains(@aria-label,'Invite')]`.
So, instead of using this `all_connect_buttons = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'button')` you can use this:

```py
all_connect_buttons = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@aria-label,'Invite')]")
```

This can also be done with CSS Selectors

```py
all_connect_buttons = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-label*='Invite']")
```

Comment: That only gives the Connect buttons. What I need is get only names that have Connect button next to them.

Comment: I answered here accordingly to what you asked. I can also give this solution, but this is an additional, new question while according to stackoverflow rules each question should be about one, specific issue. So, if you want us to help you with this, please open a new question for that. This will also be better for you since this question is no more on the top of the feed while the new question will appear on the top of the feed of all related followers who may be interested in this issue or maybe will wish to help.

Comment: Sure I will do that. But first want to try some ideas to see if I can find a solution. Thanks!

Comment: Right. This is always the right approach - try doing that yourself and only if you couldn't - ask for help. This is only the way to learn things.